# How do you refer to a custom XML layout from another custom XML layout?

Tags: android, layout, xml-layout

Given an [XML layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) (call it the "inner" layout), how do you refer to that inner layout from another custom XML layout (call it the "outer" layout)? Is this possible using XML alone, or are the only solutions programmatic?

Inner layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="6dip"
  >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/productImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/productName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/productImage"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Outer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  <!-- Embed inner XML layout here -->
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/productButtonAddToShoppingList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="<!-- refer to inner layout -->"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:text="add to shopping list"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you use [the <include /> tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#include-element) like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/inner_layout" />
```

See also: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html